# Replace column values based on row criteria

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

Trying to replace specific column values with NA based on specific row criteria in a data frame. Example dataset (test) and the code I have tried are below. Note that my actual dataset is much larger but I essentially need to replace specific columns in specific rows (certain years) with NA. In the example I'm trying to use column indexing to insert NAs for columns 3:5 for year 2002, but the result ends up replacing all values in columns 3:5 with NAs. I do want to use column indexing instead of column names because I have many columns in my actual data.

```
test <- data.frame(YEAR=c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004),
    zone=c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'),
    value=c(5,9,2,5,7,1,8,4,2,1),
    value2=c(5,3,6,8,9,7,2,6,1,7),
    value3=c(1,5,7,3,9,1,8,2,9,8))

ifelse(test$YEAR==2002,test[,3:5]<-NA,test[])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
test[,3:5] <- lapply(test[,3:5], replace, test$YEAR == 2002, NA)
test
#    YEAR zone value value2 value3
# 1  2000    A     5      5      1
# 2  2001    A     9      3      5
# 3  2002    A    NA     NA     NA
# 4  2003    A     5      8      3
# 5  2004    A     7      9      9
# 6  2000    B     1      7      1
# 7  2001    B     8      2      8
# 8  2002    B    NA     NA     NA
# 9  2003    B     2      1      9
# 10 2004    B     1      7      8
```

Walk-through:

- The base call is `replace(x, test$YEAR == 2002, NA)`, which replaces each value of `x` (to be determined) with an `NA` if the respective year is 2002; values that do not correspond to year of 2002 are preserved;
- `lapply(test[,3:5], replace, test$YEAR == 2002, NA)` is equivalent to

  ```r
  lapply(test[,3:5], function(x) replace(x, test$YEAR == 2002, NA))
  ```

  and is operating on each of columns 3-5. For each column it calls the `replace` function, and returns the results.
- `lapply` is going to return a list. Since we only want to replace a few columns of the whole frame, we do `test[,3:5] <-`, keeping the rest of the columns.

Side note:

This could have been done with `ifelse` as well, and that would have looked like:

```r
lapply(test[,3:5], function(x) ifelse(test$YEAR == 2002, NA, x))
```

I tend to prefer `replace` over `ifelse` in situations like this that are very well defined. Why? (1) `replace` is smaller and faster. (2) `ifelse` has numerous problems de-`class`ing columns, see for example `ifelse(TRUE,Sys.time(),Sys.time())`. (3) `ifelse` when used incorrectly silently coerces things, it can return different classes without warning or error. While this might be desirable, it may not be expected, and it is *silent*. See how `ifelse(c(T,F), c(pi,pi), c("hello","hello"))` will always return a `character` vector, which may not be desired.

Regardless, I have never seen one instance of `ifelse` where it made sense to make assignments within the call. That is, none of these (to me) ever makes sense:

```
ifelse(a <- foo > bar, ..., ...)
ifelse(..., b <- 1, ...)
ifelse(..., b[2:9] <- 11, ...)
```

Comment: Well that just worked perfectly! Many thanks @r2evans

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a tidyverse solution:

```
test %>%
  mutate(across(contains("value"), ~if_else(YEAR == 2002, NA_real_, .)))
```

or

```
test %>%
  mutate(across(contains("value"), ~replace(., YEAR == 2002, NA)))
```

gives

```
#    YEAR zone value value2 value3
# 1  2000    A     5      5      1
# 2  2001    A     9      3      5
# 3  2002    A    NA     NA     NA
# 4  2003    A     5      8      3
# 5  2004    A     7      9      9
# 6  2000    B     1      7      1
# 7  2001    B     8      2      8
# 8  2002    B    NA     NA     NA
# 9  2003    B     2      1      9
# 10 2004    B     1      7      8
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. I do use tidyverse often.